# Definition of witness property in Marker's "Model theory - An introduction"

Tags: definition, model-theory, witness-property

In David Marker's "Model theory - An introduction" he defines the witness property in the context of Henkin constructions as:

[image]

In the Erratum he says that in this definition, it should have been $(\exists \phi(v)\to \phi(c))\in T$ instead of $T\models (\exists \phi(v)\to\phi(c))$.

However, I've googled "Witness property" online and found the definition in various texts as:
$\ $

[image]

or for example:

[image]

So is Marker's correction wrong and the original definition correct?

Comment: $\vdash$ is used for syntax (e.g. $T \vdash \varphi$) et and $\vDash$ for semantics (e.g. $\mathcal{M} \vDash \varphi$ where $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of $T$). Here, the author clearly wants to talk of the theory $T$ syntactically so you should use $\vdash$ and not $\vDash.$

Comment: but $T\vdash (\exists \phi(v)\to \phi(c))\iff T\models (\exists \phi(v)\to \phi(c))$. Definition 2.5 is the same as fact 1 and definition 2.1.5 @Noether

Comment: @Noether $\vdash$ is commonly used to denote semantic consequence in a context like model theory where there's no risk of confusinon.

Comment: While it is true that $T\vdash (\exists \phi(v)\to \phi(c))\iff T\models (\exists \phi(v)\to \phi(c))$, the proof of this depends on the completeness theorem, which is usually done with the Henkin argument. To avoid circularity, you can't use this fact at this point.

Answer (score 1):

A structure $M$ can have the witness property by having enough constants to witness the truth of satisfiable well-formed formulas, in which case it would be correct to say that: for all $\varphi$, $M \models [\exists v](\varphi(v)) \to \varphi(c)$.

I would argue that for a theory the notation $\models$ isn't totally wrong, since $\Gamma \models \varphi$ can be used to denote semantic consequence.

Anyway, a theory is a set of sentences, so the erratum $[\exists v](\varphi(v)) \to \varphi(c) \in T$ denotes that the well-formed formula is in $T$ directly $T$ and $T \vdash [\exists v](\varphi(v)) \to \varphi(c)$ denotes that $[\exists v](\varphi(v)) \to \varphi(c)$ is a syntactic consequence of $T$.

In any of these notations, $[\exists v](\varphi(v)) \to \varphi(c)$ is in the deductive closure of $T$, perhaps trivially, which is what we're after.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that we don't know that the relation $T\models\varphi$ works anywhere close to the way we'd like it to till after the compactness theorem is proven. If $T$ has no models, then we have $T\models \exists x\varphi(x)\to \varphi(c)$ always, regardless if the sentence is included in $T.$ And more generally, we have $T\models \varphi$ for every sentence, whereas at most one of $\varphi$ and $\lnot \varphi$ is contained in $T$ when $T$ is finitely satisfiable.

Contrast the case of the analogous proof of the completeness theorem, where we know at that outset that a maximal (deductively) consistent theory $T$ has $\varphi \in T$ if and only if $T\vdash \varphi,$ and so the distinction is moot for the purposes of proving the completeness theorem.

If $T\models \varphi$ were instead initially defined to mean that there is a finite subset of $T$ such that every model of that subset satisfies $\varphi$, then we could use $\varphi\in T$ and $T\models \varphi$ interchangibly when $T$ is a maximal finitely satisfiable theory. This "more manifestly $\vdash$-like" definition can be useful in adapting things from the syntax side to the semantic side without having to go through the completeness theorem, e.g. if you want to define a semantic version of the Lindenbaum algebra and prove compactness from the ultrafilter lemma.

(Thanks to Michael Weiss for pointing out my original answer completely missed the point.)

Comment: It’s an error because the equivalence you mention isn’t available yet, even with a maximal theory. You’re entitled to claim that equivalence only after finishing the proof of the model existence theorem. But the witness property is one of the ingredients of the proof.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss Yes, I see now, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Not quite sure about your distinction between the completeness theorem and the compactness theorem. Until the model existence theorem is proven, one doesn't know that $T\vdash \varphi$ is the same as $T\models\varphi$. $T\vdash\varphi$ iff $\varphi\in T$ for a maximally consistent theory, while true, isn't enough to prove the MET (which is basically the same as the completeness theorem).

Comment: @MichaelWeiss agree with the first assertion of course. You prove model existence the same way in either case (compactness or completeness), by constructing the term model, with minor variations in how you justify things. The point I’m making is that the completeness theorem side, it doesn’t make a difference whether you define things like $c\sim d$ iff $T\vdash c=d$ or iff $c=d\in T$ (which seems to be the upshot of the question) whereas it does make a difference for the compactness theorem with $\models$ in place of $\vdash$.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss (to be clear: I’m talking about completeness in the form “every consistent set of sentences has a model” vs compactness “every finitely satisfiable set of sentences has a model” and proving either via Henkinize+maximize+term model, the only difference being more tedium in justifying steps on the completeness side for obvious reasons.)